# Unable to paste files on sd card on ubuntu

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, external-sd, linux

I am unable to paste files on SD card of my phone connected to Ubuntu pc in MTP mode.

When I try to paste files, it shows the following error.

```
There was an error creating the directory in mtp://[usb:001,004]/Card.
```

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions on [14.04 Cannot create/delete/manipulate files on my Android device via USB](http://askubuntu.com/questions/529477/14-04-cannot-create-delete-manipulate-files-on-my-android-device-via-usb)? These may work :)

Comment: tried that,, but nothing works..

Answer (score 0):

If Linux thinks the card's filesystem may be damaged (i.e., wasn't removed safely/unmounted cleanly) then it will force it to mount in read-only mode.

If you are fairly sure it's OK, you can remove the card from the phone and put it in a card reader, then force it to mount in terminal (assuming it shows up as `/dev/sdc1`, and you make a folder `/mnt/usb` for it):

```
sudo mount -o rw,nonempty /dev/sdc1 /mnt/usb
```

Try that. If it works for you, be sure to unmount it properly when you are done. Next time you try to access it through your phone you should be fine.

If not, you may want to check that your account has permissions/group memberships to appropriate groups (or cheat and run Nautilus with `sudo`).

Good luck!